# Box2D: Convert Images into Physics body

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, box2d, game-physics

I want to convert my image which is a `.bmp` file into a physics body. I have tried but it does not work i.e I do not get the desired result. I have searched alot about it o google and finally asking you all to please help me out as I am new to it. Also I am wondering is there really a way to convert images into a box2D body or We simple cannot do that ? I have tried the following code :

My addBrick Function

```
b2Body* addBrick(int x,int y,int w,int h,bool dyn=true)
{

    b2BodyDef bodydef;  
    bodydef.position.Set(x*P2M,y*P2M);   //Setting body position
    if(dyn)
    {
            bodydef.type=b2_dynamicBody;  // dynamic body means body will move

    }

    b2Body* body=world->CreateBody(&bodydef);        //Creating box2D body

    b2PolygonShape shape;            //Creating shape object
    shape.SetAsBox(P2M*w,P2M*h);

    ////////////// Adding Fixtures(mass, density etc) //////////////

    b2FixtureDef fixturedef;
    fixturedef.shape=&shape;
    fixturedef.density=1.0;
    fixturedef.restitution = 0.7;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixturedef);
    return body;
}
```

drawbrick logic:

```
void drawbrick()
{
    pix[0].readBMPFile("brick.bmp");
    pix[0].mDraw();


}
```

declaration as b2Body

```
b2Body* myBrick;
```

calling functions:

```
myBrick = addBrick(100,0,10,10);
drawbrick();
```

Where am I going wrong? Can somebody please spot my mistakes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most effective way I have found to convert any sort of image into a Box2D body is by using the PhysicsEditor tool ([link](http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor)).  I'm not affiliated with them and I am an independent software developer developer.

The editor allows you to import your image then automatically create polygons that you can import into a "shape cache" and then load into the bodies when you create them.

The Shape Cache API (which you can also get from their site) looks like this:

```
class Box2DShapeCache
   {
    public:
        // Static interface
        static Box2DShapeCache& instance(void);

    public:
        bool init();
        void addShapesWithFile(const std::string &plist);
      b2Fixture* addHullFixtureToBody(b2Body *body, const std::string &shape);

      /* Shapes created in the physics editor are in pixel dimensions.  When they are loaded
       * they are normalized to the size of maximum of the width/height.
       *
       */
        void addFixturesToBody(b2Body *body, const std::string &shape, float32 scaleMeters);
        CCPoint anchorPointForShape(const string& shape);
      CCSize imageSizeForShape(const string& shape);
      const std::vector<b2Vec2>& hullPointsForShape(const std::string &shape);
        void reset();
        float getPtmRatio() { return ptmRatio; }
        ~Box2DShapeCache() {}

    private:
        std::map<std::string, BodyDef *> shapeObjects;
        Box2DShapeCache(void) {}
        float ptmRatio;
    };
```

NOTE 1 - I have used this with Cocos2d-x very effectively.  In the video here ([link](http://nonlinearideas.com/state-of-the-art/)), it was used to create the asteroids the spiders are walking on.

NOTE 2 - The original class was called GB2ShapeCache.  It was written in objective-c and has been ported ([here](https://github.com/hannon235/GBox2DX/blob/channon_gles20/Classes/GB2ShapeCache.h)) to C++.  If you need another C++ version, let me know (mine is slightly modded to import convex hulls from the tool) and I can help.

Was this helpful?

Comment: I need something that can work with c++ and opengl. I have no clue about cocos2d-x and objective-C

Comment: Cocos2d-x is C++ and it works with OpenGL to do all the drawing.  It is also fully integrated with Box2d.